# checking if a radio button is selected

Tags: java, android, xml

i have a radio button group which contains 4 radio buttons none of them is checked by default

```
  <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ans11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/q"
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:textColor="#747577"
            android:textSize="35dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ans22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ans11"
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:textColor="#747577"
            android:textSize="35dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ans33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/memberexdone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ans22"
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:textColor="#747577"
            android:textSize="35dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ans44"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/memberexdone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ans22"
            android:text="RadioButton"
            android:textColor="#747577"
            android:textSize="35dp" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

im trying to check if clicked on a button without selecting any of the radio buttons ..

```
  rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            rbtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            String selected = rbtn.getText().toString();
            if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
            {
                //if the password less than 8 or more than 10
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder3=new AlertDialog.Builder(MemberExercise.this);
                alertBuilder3.setTitle("Invalid");
                alertBuilder3.setMessage("Please select an answer first, then click on done.");
                alertBuilder3.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();


                    }
                });

                alertBuilder3.create().show();
            }
            else
            {
                .....
            }
```

also tried 
        if (rbtn.equals("")){}

but both when i click on the button without selecting any .. the application will stop ..why ?

Comment: Is all this code with `if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)` inside button click or outside?

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ inside the onClikListener

Comment: Please post logcat output. That will help us in helping you.

Comment: you can, logcat can show error irrespective of device.

Comment: instead of "-1" use "0"

Comment: correction. instead of  "== -1" use "< 0"

Comment: use this  `// find the radiobutton by returned id rbtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);` in else part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to check `== -1` before `getText()`, otherwise `rbtn`  will be `NULL` and `rbtn.getText()` will cause `NPE`

```
    int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if (selectedId == -1)
    {
        //if the password less than 8 or more than 10
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder3=new AlertDialog.Builder(MemberExercise.this);
        alertBuilder3.setTitle("Invalid");
        alertBuilder3.setMessage("Please select an answer first, then click on done.");
        alertBuilder3.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertBuilder3.create().show();
        return;
    }

    // find the radiobutton by returned id
    rbtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
    String selected = rbtn.getText().toString();
```